# Tomcat migration to WebLogic12

Tags: spring, tomcat, migration, weblogic

all
  Recently I migrate a webapp from tomcat7 to Weblogic12, the jdk version is 1.6.0.30. After I deploy the project war completed, open the login page(/login.htm), ie throw such an exception:

> Error 404--Not Found   From RFC 2068 Hypertext Transfer Protocol --
>   HTTP/1.1:
>   10.4.5 404 Not Found The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI. No indication is given of whether the condition is
>   temporary or permanent.
>
> If the server does not wish to make this information available to the
>   client, the status code 403 (Forbidden) can be used instead. The 410
>   (Gone) status code SHOULD be used if the server knows, through some
>   internally configurable mechanism, that an old resource is permanently
>   unavailable and has no forwarding address

.

**Here is My Web.xml File:**

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <web-app version="2.5"
> xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
> xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
> xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
> http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
> <display-name>sys</display-name>
> <description>JSP application</description>
> <context-param>
> <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
> <param-value>
>   classpath:spring/framework-data.xml,
>   classpath:spring/framework-common.xml,
>   classpath:spring/framework-query.xml
> </param-value>
> </context-param>
> <!--encoding-->
> <filter>
> <filter-name>sessionFilter</filter-name>
> <filter-class>com.wri.hy.framework.application.framework.security.controller.SessionFilter</filter-class>
> <init-param>
> <param-name>encoding</param-name>
> <param-value>utf-8</param-value>
> </init-param>
> <init-param>
> <param-name>isCheck</param-name>
> <param-value>true</param-value>
> </init-param>
> </filter>
> <filter-mapping>
> <filter-name>sessionFilter</filter-name>
> <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
> </filter-mapping>
> <listener>
> <listener-class>com.wri.hy.framework.application.framework.security.controller.SessionListener</listener-class>
> </listener>
>
> <!--spring-->
> <servlet>
> <servlet-name>framework</servlet-name>
> <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
> <init-param>
> <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
> <param-value>classpath:spring/framework-servlet.xml</param-value>
> </init-param>
> <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
> </servlet>
> <!--surpport WebApplicationContextUtils-->
> <servlet>
> <servlet-name>context</servlet-name>
> <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderServlet</servlet-class>
> <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
> </servlet>
> <!--Watcher-->
>   <servlet>
> <servlet-name>watcher</servlet-name>
> <servlet-class>com.wri.hy.framework.application.framework.util.Watcher</servlet-class>
> <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
>   </servlet>
> <servlet>
> <servlet-name>DisplayChart</servlet-name>
> <servlet-class>org.jfree.chart.servlet.DisplayChart</servlet-class>
> </servlet>
> <servlet-mapping>
> <servlet-name>DisplayChart</servlet-name>
> <url-pattern>/servlet/displayChart</url-pattern>
> </servlet-mapping>
> <servlet-mapping>
> <servlet-name>framework</servlet-name>
> <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
> </servlet-mapping>
>
> <session-config>
>   <session-timeout>240</session-timeout>
>   </session-config>
> <welcome-file-list>
> <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
> <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
> <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
> </welcome-file-list>
> <!--error-page>
> <error-code>404</error-code>
> <location>/fileNotFound.html</location>
> </error-page-->
> </web-app>
> ```

What can I do for this problem? Here is an active place for puzzles,any response is apprieated. Thanks.

Comment: The title of your question indicates migrating to "Websphere12", but I assume this should be "WebLogic 12"? Likewise, you may want to update your tags accordingly as well.

Answer (score 0):

problem resolvered, It sourced by load-on-startup tag value, defined web.xml. Must be different on weblogic.

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>framework</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:spring/framework-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <!--surpport WebApplicationContextUtils-->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>context</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

Thanks.